# asp.net MVC - Bizarre Index out of Range when iterating Dictionary in Razor View ONLY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting a strange 'Index was out Range' exception when iterating through my viewmodel's dictionary property which is simply int Key and List of objects as Value.  It is strange because the exception only occurs when iterating through the dictionary in the Razor View.  Just for the sake of my own sanity, I ran the exact same iteration process in my controller without any problems.  Here is the code for that:

```
        Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.PhaseTemplateDict.Keys.Count(); i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Phase Name: " + viewModel.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[0].ProgramLevelName);
            Debug.WriteLine("");

            for (int j = 0; j < viewModel.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i).Count(); j++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Goal Name: " + viewModel.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].GoalDescription);                    
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("=========================");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

This produces the desired output, no exceptions.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Phase Name: Orientation

Goal Name: Provider
Goal Name: UAs
Goal Name: P.O. Meeting
Goal Name: Provider Assessment
Goal Name: Court
=========================
Phase Name: Phase 1

Goal Name: School/Work
Goal Name: Treatment
Goal Name: Curfew Checks
Goal Name: PO Meetings
Goal Name: UAs
Goal Name: Court
=========================
Phase Name: Phase 2

Goal Name: test1
Goal Name: test2
=========================
Phase Name: Phase 3

Goal Name: test1
Goal Name: test2
Goal Name: test3
Goal Name: test4
=========================
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

However when I use a nearly identical structure in my razor view to build a table, I get a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection'. View:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.PhaseTemplatesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
            @{ int index = 0;}
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Keys.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">@Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[0].ProgramLevelName</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>                                        
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Points Required</th>
                                        <th>Display Order</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @for (int j = 0; j < @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i).Count(); j++)
                                    {                                        
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(mdlItem => @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].PointMatrixTemplateID, new { Name = "[" + index + "]." + "PointMatrixTemplateID" })
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(mdlItem => @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].ProgramLevel, new { Name = "[" + index + "]." + "ProgramLevel" })

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(mdlItem => @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].GoalDescription, new { @class = "form-control", Name = "[" + index + "]." + "GoalDescription" })
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(mdlItem => @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].PointsRequired, new { @class = "form-control text-center", style = "width: 40px; padding: 0px", type = "number", Name = "[" + index + "]." + "PointsRequired" })
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(mdlItem => @Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[j].DisplayOrder, new { @class = "form-control text-center", style = "width: 40px; padding: 0px", type = "number", Name = "[" + index + "]." + "DisplayOrder" })
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        index++;
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addGoalToTemplate(@Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[i].ProgramLevel)">Add Goal</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

In this case the exception occurs as soon as execution reaches the top of inner for loop for the 3rd time. Which is at Key[2] ('Phase 2' above).  I have been able to get the View to render successfully when the length of the list (Dictionary Value) is greater than or equal to the index of the Dictionary Key which it is mapped to.  For instance in the debug output above, 'Phase 2' is at  the 3rd Key index [2], but its Value list only has a Count of 2, so the exception occurs.  Strangely, if I make that Value list have a Count of 3 or more, everything works fine.  I've been scratching my head over this one for a while, so any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why bother making it a dictionary if you are going to treat it as an array?  For easier iteration I generally use something like `foreach (var k in dict.Keys)` for dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I'm feeling pretty dumb.

Typo on the indexes for this button caused the problem

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addGoalToTemplate(@Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[i].ProgramLevel)">Add Goal</button>
```

Should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="addGoalToTemplate(@Model.PhaseTemplateDict.Values.ElementAt(i)[0].ProgramLevel)">Add Goal</button>
```

I just changed the indexes on the 'ElementAt' from (i)[i] to (i)[0].